# How to insert json to mysql database wp / php - numbers, strings and timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, json, wordpress, rest

I hope you can guide me with the following:

I am sending a http post request in json to wordpress REST Api, like this:

```
{"item1":26.62,"item2":319,"item3":4445,"payload":"0a66013f115d0001088f013c05", "timestamp": "2020-06-26 19:34:31", "device": "xx"}
```

Now in php i have the following to store this in the wordpress connected mysql database, in a custom table, like this:

```
function handle_post( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
global $wpdb;
$item = $request->get_json_params();$fields = array();
$values = array();
foreach($item as $key => $val) {
    array_push($fields, preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", '', $key));
    array_push($values, $wpdb->prepare('%f', $val));
}
$fields = implode(", ", $fields);
$values = implode(", ", $values);
$query = "INSERT INTO `tablename_xxx` ($fields) VALUES ($values)";
$list = $wpdb->get_results($query);

return $list;}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {   register_rest_route( 'data/v1', '/005', array(     'methods' => 'POST',     'callback' => 'handle_post', ) );} );
```

I found this code and it works, but this is only converting the numbers / floats. How should I proceed to include the two key value pairs that contain a string (both numbers and letters). And how can I store the Timestamp? Also, these strings and timestamp are always included, the number of 'items' with values may differ.

Next, is it possible to use one of the pairs, the value of it, to store it in a (custom) table with matching value in the table title? Can I use a variable somehow?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$wpdb->prepare('%f', $val)` should only convert numbers.

There should be some distinction between numbers and strings. For example, you know in advance which of your fields you want to convert to numbers and which you want to convert to strings *even if it happens to be a pure number* (e.g. 'payload' may be pure number, but you still want to save it as a string).

```php
$fieldTypes = [
    "item1"     => '%f',
    "item2"     => '%f',
    "item3"     => '%f',
    "payload"   => '%s'
    "timestamp" => '%s',
    "device"    => '%s'
];
```

Then, inside the `foreach` loop, instead of `$wpdb->prepare('%f', $val)`, use: `$wpdb->prepare($fieldTypes[$key], $val)`.

Comment: Thank you for your solution!

Comment: You can also mark the answer as 'accepted', so that people with a similar problem will see it.